# Correctly locating a string in string array

Tags: asp.net, arrays, string, list

I have an array of strings that contains usernames that I'd like to extract and add it to a list. So for example, I have this string => "`UserName: JohnSmith`" and I want to extract `JohnSmith`. The below is the code I'm attempting to get working:

```
var documentSource = content.Replace("\n" , "").Trim();
string[] contents = documentSource.Split(',');

List<Model> modelList = new List<Model>();
Model model = new Model();

foreach (var item in contents)
{
    //this is where I'd like to locate the username or usernames
    if(item.Any())
    {
        model.userName = //username only;
        modelList.Add(model);
    }
}

return modelList;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the kind of problem that can be easily solved with [regular expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/regular-expressions):

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

// ...

var regex = new Regex("UserName: ([^,]*)");

// ..

foreach(var item in contents)
{
    var match = regex.Match(item);
    if(match.Success)
    {
         modelList.Add(
            new Model 
            { 
               userName = match.Groups[1].Value 
            }
         );
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you @Andrew Shepherd. That helped me plenty.

Comment: What if you have `Username: John123, strings right after the username`. How can I just retrieve `John123`?

Comment: @JennyFromtheBlock The regular expression can be easily changed. (I'll modify my answer so that commas are excluded). Check out this site so you can test them. http://regexstorm.net/tester

Answer (score 1):

In it's simplest form, since you know that each username start after `"UserName: "` part that is fixed, it would be something like this:

```cs
var documentSource = content.Replace("\n" , "").Trim();
string[] contents = documentSource.Split(',', StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

var modelList = new List<Model>();

foreach (var item in contents)
{
    var username = item.Substring("UserName: ".Length).Trim();
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(username))
    {
        Model model = new Model();
        model.userName = username;
        modelList.Add(model);
    }
}

return modelList;
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you know that you have one `:` inside of the username string and the second part of the `:` is your actual username that you want, so, you can split the string in two parts and get the second one. Something like below:

```
foreach (var item in contents)
{
    var username = item.Split(':').Last()?.Trim();
    if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(username))
    {
      modelList.Add(new Model{ userName = username });
    }
}
```